# Scala convert Map[String, Set[String]] to Map[(String, String), Option[Double]]

Tags: scala

I was thinking of a way to create a tuple consisting of the String key from the map along with each of the Strings from the Set together as tuple that form the key in a new map. Value for the new map will be initialized to 0.0.

Ex: If I have to following:

```
Map[ USA, Set[CA, NY, WA]]
```

I want to create a new map from this which looks like:

```
Map[(USA,CA) -> 0.0, (USA,NY) -> 0.0, (USA,WA) -> 0.0]
```

I am able to create a `Map[String, String]` but I was hoping to get some help in creating the tuple key.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Map("USA" -> Set("CA", "NY", "WA")) flatMap { case (k, set) => set.map((k, _) -> 0.0) }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
val myMap = Map("USA" -> Set("CA", "NY", "WA"))

val newMap = myMap.foldLeft(Map[(String, String), Double]()) {
  case (acc, (key, values)) => {
    acc ++ (for {
      value <- values
    } yield (key, value) -> 0.0)
  }
}
```